# Can I initialize two variables in an SSIS For Loop Container?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there any way to initialize the value of two variables in the InitExpression of a For Loop Container in SSIS?

For example:

```
InitExpression:   @BeginDate = (DT_DBTIMESTAMP) "1/1/1900"; @EndDate = (DT_DBTIMESTAMP) "1/1/2007"
EvalExpression:   @BeginDate < GETDATE()
AssignExpression: @BeginDate = @EndDate; @EndDate = DATEADD("Month", 1, @EndDate)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible.  However, you could set the @EndDate variable definition as an expression and make it do these calculations in the expression.  The For Loop Container would only increment the @BeginDate and the @EndDate would change as it changes.

Comment: That would work except that I need @BeginDate to start at 1/1/1900 and then derive from @EndDate after that.  I ended up using a Script Task before the loop and at the end of the loop instead.  But thanks for your response.